# Moodle .doc to .pdf conversion doesn't work

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, moodle, doc

When I go to grading and click to attribute a grade to a student, an interface opens: it has a comment section, grade field, etc. and a screen where it's printed "**Generating PDF**" where the student's homework should be. Except that the PDF is *never* ever generated, it just leaves a **blank page**. It happens when the uploaded file is a Word document - didn't test it with other kinds of submission.

Print:
[An image is worth more than a thousand words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr3fQ.jpg)

I've looked it up in Moodle's forum and it seems this issue's pretty common, but I can't really understand what they are saying, 'cause it seems their solutions are directed to those who have a server at home.

My moodle is hosted on a third-party server, I'm *not* a server owner, I'm merely the website administrator. I do have access to the web hosting account, but don't have enough permissions to install/change/delete server routines and stuff that requires access to a terminal.

Is there anything that I, as a website administrator can do?

To clarify: 1 - I do not know if this is the right place to ask this questions - there are so many "stackoverflow-sites" that I can't keep track. So, feel free to move my topic.

2 - I did search if there was a similar question here and found none. If there is one, it's well hidden and I would appreciate if anyone could provide me with the link to that.

Answer (score 0):

On moodle 3.2 and 3.1 you need unoconv and libreoffice installed on server, so if you can't install software on the server - it will not work.
On 3.3 it could use google services - didn't try it yet...

Comment: Is Google Services the name of the plugin?